# How can I view all ng-init content?

Tags: angularjs, html

I am doing the progress bar for each object equipment.

Here is my AngularJS code:

```
$scope.progressBarEquipements=function(idEquipement) {

     $http.get(url+"/RestResponseCheckLists?idEq="+idEquipement)
     .success(function(data) {
             $scope.Pourcentage = data;
      }).error(function(err, data) {
            console.log("error : " +data);
    }); 
};
```

This function returns `$scope.progressBarEquipements=function(idEquipement)`:

```
console.log("data "+Pourcentage);
/**
* [{'NB_Resp':2,'NB_checks':154}]  //For the first object And the others not
*/
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="eq in Checksf" ng-init="progressBarEquipements(eq.idEquipements)">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" >{{eq.nomEq}} </h4>  
        <div class="progress progress-lg m-b-5" >
               <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-purple" role="progressbar" ng-repeat="p in Pourcentage" ng-style="{width:{{((p.NB_Resp/p.NB_checks) * 100)}} + '%'}">
                  {{((p.NB_Resp/p.NB_checks) * 100) | number:0}}%
           </div>
     </div>                
</div>
```

So I have four items of equipment are displayed in the html page.

> The `$scope.Percentage` displays the progress bar calculation for the
>   first object only.

How to display for each object its calculation in the progress bar?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, I don't like the way you are using ng-init, the following should work :

```
$scope.progressBarEquipements=function(eq) {

     $http.get(url+"/RestResponseCheckLists?idEq="+ eq.idEquipement)
     .success(function(data) {
         eq.Pourcentage = data;
      }).error(function(err, data) {
            console.log("error : " +data);
    }); 
};

<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="eq in Checksf" ng-init="progressBarEquipements(eq)">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" >{{eq.nomEq}} </h4>  
        <div class="progress progress-lg m-b-5" >
               <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-purple" role="progressbar" ng-repeat="p in eq.Pourcentage"  ng-style="{width:{{((p.NB_Resp/p.NB_checks) * 100)}} + '%'}">
                  {{((p.NB_Resp/p.NB_checks) * 100) | number:0}}%
           </div>
     </div>                
</div>
```

The idea was to send your function "progressBarEquipements" the full equipment object. In that way, you are able to update it when the server responds.

I don't like the approach of using ng-init because 
 - the behaviour of your view is kinda hidden between your controller, and your template.
 - If I had to do it, my API would give the viewmodel containing every information I need to display.

Comment: According to the last modification, it works with me, thank you Sir ,

Comment: I've seen your edits, and ok, I was missing "Percentage" into your object, but I don't think a ng-repeat should be there ih there is only one item each time.

Comment: `eq.Pourcentage` Returns two objects. How to browse. So, add 'ng-repeat'. I tested this case and it works with me